# Zabbix server port 10051 not listening

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, proxy, zabbix

I have a Zabbix agent and a master server. In both servers, the port 10050 is working fine but unable to connect the Zabbix agent to the master server because the port 10051 is closed. I have seen the connection with the 10051 port in both servers (by Telneting IP address & port) it works fine. I have tried with `netstat -na | grep :10051` it’s not working. I am using Google Cloud Platform and created a new rule for the firewall opening the port 10051 though it's not working.
This is what I'm getting when I write `netstat -vatn` :

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10050           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43283         127.0.0.1:4369          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.128.0.3:36780        173.194.74.95:443       TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.128.0.3:50438        173.194.194.95:443      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32000         127.0.0.1:31000         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.128.0.3:53766        142.250.148.95:443      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0     64 10.128.0.3:22           35.235.244.33:43763     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.128.0.3:53416        169.254.169.254:80      ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Please provide your Zabbix server configuration

Comment: provide also `lsof -i :10051`

Answer (score 0):

Highly likely your Zabbix server is not configured to listen on 10051 as it usually is commented out by default. Take a look at your config and you may find this:

`# ListenPort=10051`

Remove `#`, restart zabbix server and check `netstat` again.